# C++ why use TLB files over the actual DLL?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have some legacy C++ code.

I have DLL Bob.
I also have program Jane.

Program Jane imports Bob through his TLB file.

```
#import 'Bob.tlb'
```

Why does Jane use Bob like that?

Why doesn't Jane use Bob like this?

```
#import 'Bob.dll'
```

I have the source code for both sides.
Thanks for any help or pointers!

Comment: I consider myself an experimented C++ guy, but never heard of `#import`... A Microsoft thing, I assume. Could you tag with visual-studio (and version) to clarify.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx for reference.

Comment: I liked the way you named the libraries!

Comment: With #import Jane has automatic synchronization of definitions Bob created and published through type library. Bob is updated, then you rebuild Jane and either sync with the changes or have build errors. Easy, reliable, powerful. Import from DLL is nothing but import from TLB embedded into that DLL. On the one hand, DLL is sufficient for import. On the other hand you might prefer standalone TLB, e.g. if you build it from IDL without embedding into binaries, or prior to embedding into binaries.

Comment: @RomanR. That's great information and what I was looking for. Ta!

Answer (score 5):

`#import`ing a dll is equivalent to importing a tlb only when the dll contains the type library as the resource of `ITypeLib` type, as dictated by [`LoadTypeLib`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221027(v=vs.85).aspx) API call.

This is not always the case:

- the dll doesn't have to contain the tlb as the resource
- you might want to use a managed dll via COM interop: the dll doesn't contain the tlb and you have to generate it using `tlbexp` tool
- there are probably other scenarios

Answer (score 1):

TLB is type definition, which also can includes in DLL.
If you directly use #import *.tlb or #import *.dll, the MIDL Compiler would generate .tlh and .thi which used in following compiling steps.

It's not a good choice to directly #import. 
If you #import the same .tlb in different cpp in same project, would introduce duplication .tlh & .tli files generated.